# DBMS_XMLGEN package body source containing random alphabets

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-ebs

I am trying to run a sql query to dbms_xmlgen.getxml. It errors out saying Invalid number. On checking the error stacks it points to lines 7,147 in SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN. Tried to get the source code. But package code is just random alphabets. Where can i get this C code for DBMS_XMLGEN?

Answer (score 1):

The stored source starts:

```
PACKAGE BODY dbms_xmlgen wrapped
a000000
1
abcd
abcd
...
```

Aside from recognising the format, the key thing in there is the word 'wrapped' - [read more about that](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm). While there are unofficial tools out there to unwrap code, I wouldn't recommend it, for ethical and probably legal reasons.

You should not need to look at the code anyway though. The problem is almost certainly in your code, not in Oracle's. Look again at what you're doing, and if you can't figure out where the error is coming from, include your code in the question, along with the DDL of any tables you're referring to.